# Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

The full error I get is:

> *Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

I was passed by this SQL code that used to work in the past and I need to fix it, but I get the error above, but even if I comment out some parts the error stays the same

Here is the sql code:

```
SELECT  
    OrderId = OrdNameAdd.ORDERS_ID,
    LTRIM(ISNULL(OrdNameAdd.OBY_FirstName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(OrdNameAdd.OBY_LASTNAME, '')) AS OrderedByName,
    ObyVar1 = (SELECT varfld_value FROM MAILERVBL WHERE OBYMAILER = MAILERVBL.MAILER_SEQID AND VARDEF_SEQUENCE = 1),
    ObyVar2 = (SELECT varfld_value FROM MAILERVBL WHERE OBYMAILER = MAILERVBL.MAILER_SEQID AND VARDEF_SEQUENCE = 2),
    ObyVar3 = (SELECT varfld_value FROM MAILERVBL WHERE OBYMAILER = MAILERVBL.MAILER_SEQID AND VARDEF_SEQUENCE = 3),
    ExtendedDefaultValue = (SELECT sum(isnull(p.prduct_value,0) *  (isnull(pickdt.prdord_toshipqty,1))) 
                            FROM PICKDT 
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                               locVerBals ON PICKDT.PRVERS_SEQID = locVerBals.PRVERS_Seqid 
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                               LOCPRDSUM p ON locVerBals.PRDUCT_Seqid = p.PRDUCT_SEQID 
                                           AND p.system_id = PICPAK.SYSTEM_ID 
                            WHERE
                               PICKDT.PICPAK_Seqid = PICPAK.PICPAK_Seqid 
                               AND p.PRDUCT_INACTIVEDATE IS NULL), 
    FulfCharges = (rpt_BD.Linesshipped * ACCDEF_ChargePerLine) + ACCDEF_ChargePerShipment, 
    PubFreight = (rpt_BD.PubFreight), 
    TotalValue = 
        (SELECT 
            sum(isnull(p.prduct_value, 0) * (isnull(pickdt.prdord_toshipqty, 1))) 
         from PICKDT 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN locVerBals ON PICKDT.PRVERS_SEQID = locVerBals.PRVERS_Seqid 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCPRDSUM p ON locVerBals.PRDUCT_Seqid = p.PRDUCT_SEQID 
                                     AND p.system_id = PICPAK.SYSTEM_ID 
         WHERE 
             PICKDT.PICPAK_Seqid = PICPAK.PICPAK_Seqid AND p.PRDUCT_INACTIVEDATE IS NULL) 
         + isnull((rpt_BD.Linesshipped * ACCDEF_ChargePerLine), 0) 
         + isnull(ACCDEF_ChargePerShipment,0) + isnull((rpt_BD.PubFreight), 0)
FROM 
    PICPAK 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ORDSTO ON PICPAK.ORDSTO_Seqid = ORDSTO.ORDSTO_Seqid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    OrdNameAdd ON ORDSTO.ORDERS_Seqid = OrdNameAdd.ORDERS_SEQID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Rpt_BillingDetail rpt_BD ON PICPAK.PICPAK_Seqid = rpt_BD.PICPAK_Seqid 

---------------hERE
WHERE 
    (convert(datetime, DateShipped, 1) >= '4/17/2012' 
     AND convert(datetime, DateShipped, 1) <= '12/17/2012')
---------------HERE

    AND (PICPAK.PICPAK_Status = 'Complete' OR PICPAK.PICPAK_Status = 'Shipped' 
         OR picpak_Status = 'Voided') 
    /*AND (p.PRDUCT_INACTIVEDATE IS NULL)*/
    AND ISNULL(PICPAK.SUPPLR_SEQID,0) = 0
GROUP BY
    OrdNameAdd.ORDERS_ID,
    OrdNameAdd.OBY_FirstName,
    OrdNameAdd.OBY_LASTNAME,
    OrdNameAdd.obymailer,
    PICPAK.PICPAK_Seqid,
    PICPAK.System_Id,
    rpt_BD.PubFreight,
    ACCDEF_ChargePerLine,
    ACCDEF_ChargePerShipment,
    rpt_BD.Linesshipped,
    rpt_BD.Numpackages,
    ordsto.orders_seqid
ORDER BY
    ordsto.orders_seqid ASC
```

Comment: It is probably one of the 3 `SELECT varfld_value` subqueries. Execute each of them individually to see which one returns multiple rows. Looks like the other subqueries are all non-grouped aggregates (`sum()`) so those should only be returning one row.

Comment: Comment out the `ObyVar_n_` lines and try running the query, then add the lines back one at a time.  That will likely identify the code causing the problem.  Fixing it may be a matter of adding to the appropriate `WHERE` clause to ensure that a single row is returned, adding an aggregate, e.g. `MAX()`, or rethinking the design on a rather larger scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query, you have five subqueries for ObyVar1, ObyVar2, ObyVar3, ExtendedDefaultValue, and TotalValue.

The two value subqueries are using aggregations with no `group by`, so they should be returning one value.

Your problemis in the three ObyVars.

There are simple two ways to get rid of this:

1. Aggregate the values.  So do `max(varfld_value)`.
2. Choose one value.  In SQL Server, this would be a `top 1` (in other databases, it might be `rownum = 1` or `limit 1`).

However, overall, I find `select` statements within `select` statements to be undesirable.  I would replace those three variables with a subquery in the `from` clause:

```
(select mailer_seqid,
        max(case when vardef_sequence = 1 then varfld_value end) as vv_1, 
        max(case when vardef_sequence = 2 then varfld_value end) as vv_2,
        max(case when vardef_sequence = 3 then varfld_value end) as vv_3
 from mailervbl
 group by mailer_seqid
)
```

In most cases, this should be as or more efficient than the three subqueries.

Comment: That was it man...I added max to the selects and it worked. Later on i found out that even though there should have been only one record matching the subquery, when they updated the software they inserted some null values that were matching the subquery, so MAX is not only working, but doing the exact job that it should.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to execute each sub query separately to find out which one is returning more than one record

Answer (score 1):

If you have sub queries to `SELECT columns Ex: (1)` or with `WHERE col = cluses Ex:(2)` you should make sure only a single value is returned.

```
--Ex:(1) make sure only one row returned by the sub query, 
--this case can be voided using TOP 1 from the sub query
SELECT col1, (SELECT colX from Table2 ) 
FROM Table1

--Ex:(2) this case can be avoided using IN instead =
SELECT col1, col2
FROM Table1
WHERE col3 = (SELECT colX from Table2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems no way we can identify them without having access your database, it's not advisable to write any where statement like this, not just talking about performance but also the problem you now facing.

To fix this you need either to go through the full logic and rewrite it with no sub-queries, or see if you can filter out some data via DISTINCT/TOP 1 in sub query without broke the logic itself. I suggest you rewrite it, sometimes it sounds complex but make things simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a duplicate from the sub-queries where you're doing a single SUM statement so the problem is against the MAILERVBL table.

If you're ever looking for duplicates, run the following type of code to identify your duplicates:

```
select MAILER_SEQID, VARDEF_SEQUENCE, count(*) as numentries
from MAILERVBL 
group by MAILER_SEQID, VARDEF_SEQUENCE
having count(*) > 1
order by numentries desc -- not really needed but useful to see where most of your duplicates are
```

Put whichever columns you are expecting to be unique in both your *select* and *group by* clauses.